# gsettings doesn't works to desactivate single-click in pantheon-files

Tags: pantheon-files, click

Im using Elementary OS loki and I can not desactivate the single click in pantheon-files.

I run this command on my terminal

`sudo gsettings set org.pantheon.files.preferences single-click false`

and I get the following output

`No existe el esquema «org.pantheon.files.preferences`

in Tweaks tool I don't have options for files

[image]

In english: Doesn't exist the scheme

anyone could help me? thanks!

Comment: Try without `sudo`. No need for it with gsettings commands.

Comment: I get the same output without sudo

Answer (score 1):

Changing this setting via `dconf` works for me:

`$ dconf write /org/pantheon/files/preferences/single-click false`

Can you try that?

Comment: I could solved the problem with @Jeremy Wootten answer below. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the daily unstable version you should check whether the schema io.elementary.files.preferences.single-click exists, in which case you should change that.  The Tweaks tool is not guaranteed to work with this version.

Comment: Changing the schema settings that you mention solved the problem! Thank you for the support.